# How to get the permissions of all installed apps on my phone programmatically with dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am creating Flutter app in which I have to show all the installed apps with their allowed permissions . But I don't know how to achieve this, I'm new to flutter / dart . somebody please guide me.

Comment: I don't think that is possible Tommy Shelby, MP, OBE. But hey I might be wrong ;)

Comment: I had to google the reference to Tommy Shelby, but not sure I got your meaning by it.

Comment: I think it's because of the profile picture @RandalSchwartz

Comment: you can use platform channel on flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android_package_manager` which uses the `PackageManager` API of android [here](https://pub.dev/packages/android_package_manager) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager). You can use `PackageInfo` which contains `requestedPermissions` [here](https://github.com/nsNeruno/android_package_manager/blob/master/lib/src/entities/impl/package_info.dart).

The Kotlin example is analog to the library in Flutter. The function names etc. are nearly the same. But be careful using the Flutter library. That might not work well. I would recommend using [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/pm/PackageManager) and [PackageInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/pm/PackageInfo) with platform channel of Flutter to integrate native Kotlin.

```dart
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
   Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);

   try {
      PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

      //Get Permissions
      String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

      if(requestedPermissions != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
         }
      }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```